# проблема с распознаванием речи

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread, распознавание-речи, pyaudio

Делаю простую программу распознавания речи.

Вот код:

```
# __author__ = 'ipetrash'
# /blob/879912c8236a27a817c0284a51c9f61a034b407c/speech_recognition/microphone__google.py


# pip install pyaudio
# pip install SpeechRecognition
import speech_recognition as sr

from PyQt5 import Qt


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    Qt.QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()


import sys
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


class SpeechRecognitionThread(Qt.QThread):
    about_text = Qt.pyqtSignal(str)

    language = "en-US"

    def run(self):
        try:
            r = sr.Recognizer()

            self.about_text.emit("Скажите что-нибудь...")

            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                audio = r.listen(source)

            self.about_text.emit("Анализирую речь...")

            text = r.recognize_google(audio, language=self.language)

            self.about_text.emit('Фраза: "{}"'.format(text))

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            self.about_text.emit("Робот не расслышал фразу")

        except sr.RequestError as e:
            self.about_text.emit("Ошибка сервиса: {}".format(e))

        except Exception as e:
            self.about_text.emit("Ошибка: {}".format(e))

        finally:
            self.about_text.emit('')


class Window(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('speech_recognition__microphone__google')

        self.pb_microphone = Qt.QPushButton(' SPEAK')
        self.pb_microphone.setFont(Qt.QFont('Arial', 16))

        self.cb_lang = Qt.QComboBox()
        self.cb_lang.addItems(["en-US", "ru-RU"])
        self.cb_lang.setCurrentIndex(1)

        self.pte_result = Qt.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.pte_result.setFont(Qt.QFont('Arial', 12))
        self.pte_result.setReadOnly(True)

        self.progress_bar = Qt.QProgressBar()
        self.progress_bar.setTextVisible(False)
        self.progress_bar.hide()
        self.progress_bar.setRange(0, 0)  # Infinity

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.pb_microphone)
        layout.addWidget(self.cb_lang)
        layout.addWidget(self.pte_result)
        layout.addWidget(self.progress_bar)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.thread = SpeechRecognitionThread()
        self.thread.about_text.connect(self.pte_result.appendPlainText)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.progress_bar.show)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self._speech_recognition_finish)

        # Start speech recognition
        self.pb_microphone.clicked.connect(self._speech_recognition_start)

    def _speech_recognition_start(self):
        self.pb_microphone.setEnabled(False)
        self.pte_result.clear()

        self.thread.language = self.cb_lang.currentText()
        self.thread.start()

    def _speech_recognition_finish(self):
        self.pb_microphone.setEnabled(True)
        self.progress_bar.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    w = Window()
    w.show()
    w.resize(500, 500)

    app.exec()
```

---

Но выводит так:

[image: Ошибка: No Default Input Device Available]

Почему?
Спасибо!

Comment: Я просто забыл подключить микрофон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у меня ваш пример работает правильно. я ничего не менял.

```
# pip install pyaudio
# pip install SpeechRecognition
import speech_recognition as sr

from PyQt5 import Qt


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    Qt.QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()


import sys
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


class SpeechRecognitionThread(Qt.QThread):
    about_text = Qt.pyqtSignal(str)

    language = "en-US"

    def run(self):
        try:
            r = sr.Recognizer()

            self.about_text.emit("Скажите что-нибудь...")

            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                audio = r.listen(source)

            self.about_text.emit("Анализирую речь...")

            text = r.recognize_google(audio, language=self.language)

            self.about_text.emit('Фраза: "{}"'.format(text))

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            self.about_text.emit("Робот не расслышал фразу")

        except sr.RequestError as e:
            self.about_text.emit("Ошибка сервиса: {}".format(e))

        except Exception as e:
            self.about_text.emit("Ошибка: {}".format(e))

        finally:
            self.about_text.emit('')


class Window(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('speech_recognition__microphone__google')

        self.pb_microphone = Qt.QPushButton(' SPEAK')
        self.pb_microphone.setFont(Qt.QFont('Arial', 16))

        self.cb_lang = Qt.QComboBox()
        self.cb_lang.addItems(["en-US", "ru-RU"])
        self.cb_lang.setCurrentIndex(1)

        self.pte_result = Qt.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.pte_result.setFont(Qt.QFont('Arial', 12))
        self.pte_result.setReadOnly(True)

        self.progress_bar = Qt.QProgressBar()
        self.progress_bar.setTextVisible(False)
        self.progress_bar.hide()
        self.progress_bar.setRange(0, 0)  # Infinity

        layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.pb_microphone)
        layout.addWidget(self.cb_lang)
        layout.addWidget(self.pte_result)
        layout.addWidget(self.progress_bar)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.thread = SpeechRecognitionThread()
        self.thread.about_text.connect(self.pte_result.appendPlainText)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.progress_bar.show)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self._speech_recognition_finish)

        # Start speech recognition
        self.pb_microphone.clicked.connect(self._speech_recognition_start)

    def _speech_recognition_start(self):
        self.pb_microphone.setEnabled(False)
        self.pte_result.clear()

        self.thread.language = self.cb_lang.currentText()
        self.thread.start()

    def _speech_recognition_finish(self):
        self.pb_microphone.setEnabled(True)
        self.progress_bar.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    w = Window()
    w.show()
    w.resize(500, 500)

    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а какая у вас версия python? просто у меня не работает

Comment: @Антон  Python 3.7.3

Comment: у меня python-3.7.7, по сути тоже. Значит не в этом дело.

Comment: а в ОС не может быть?

Comment: @Антон попробуйте полистать  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+no+default+input+device+available

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю!

Comment: @Антон  у меня Windows

Comment: у меня тоже....